# Trying to make JMeter login gives 500 error

Tags: html, asp-classic, jmeter, iis-8, frames

I'm trying to setup JMeter to do some stress testing on one of our applications.

So far I've been able to make it go to the login page, login to see the list of projects but when I try to make it go into a project the URL gets messed up and gives me a 500 error.

After loggin in, the URL has parameters like

`?Client_Id='CLIENT'&Project_Id='PROJECT'&System_Id=2`

When it tries to go into the project, it opens a page index.asp which builds some frames dynamically.

When building the frames, the response and the URL for each frame look fine. But, when making the actual call for each of the frames the HTTP request gets called like this:

`?Client_Id='CLIENT'<<oject_Id='PROJECT'`

Resulting in invalid query and 500 error from the server.

Comment: Getting to know what causes the 500 on the other end would certainly help ...

Comment: As mentioned on the question, it is the URL causing the 500 error. `<<` is not valid on a URL

Comment: So effectively your `&PR` gets replaced by `<<` ? Is this your problem ? Is `&System_Id=2` lost too or did you simply leave this out in your example ? My suggestion: put a proxy like membrane in between and see where the information is lost: in Jmeter or the application.

Comment: @Marged Yes, that is my problem. The application from the browser works fine. The problem is when testing with JMeter

Comment: How exactly the configuration for HTTP Request looks like? Server, Path and Parameters fields.